# Async- await function not worked properly

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I have created asynchronous function. but it takes long time(execution). function is given below.

```
    public async Task<List<EmrData>> EmrDataTransformation(string sourceJson, EMRSchema.TemplateQT emrSchema, List<double> subjectIds)
                    {
                        List<EmrData> EmrDataList = new List<EmrData>();
                        try
                        {
                            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                            foreach (var subjectId in subjectIds)
                            {
                               var GetIcuDischargeTransform = icuDataTransform.GetIcuDischargeTransform(sourceJson, emrSchema, subjectId);
                                    stringBuilder.Append("var:GetIcuDischargeTransform: ").Append(" ").Append(DateTime.Now).AppendLine();
       
                            emrData.IcuDischarge = await GetIcuDischargeTransform;
                            stringBuilder.Append("await:GetIcuDischargeTransform: ").Append(" ").Append(DateTime.Now).AppendLine();
                            File.WriteAllText($"D:\\out\\awaitcheck{subjectId}.txt", stringBuilder.ToString());
                            }
        
                        }
                        // return EmrDataList;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    }   
          return EmrDataList;
               }
```

From the above function, calling GetIcuDischargeTransform function. that function is given below.

```
public async Task<IcuDischarge> GetIcuDischargeTransform(string sourceJson, EMRSchema.TemplateQT emrSchema, double subjectId)
        {
            List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>> keyValuePairs = new List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>();

            #region Icu Discharge

            var templateIcuDischarge = emrSchema.EmrData.IcuDischarge; //emrSchema.IcuDischarge;
            var morStatus = Convert.ToString(CommonFunctions.GetData(sourceJson, templateIcuDischarge?.IcuDischargeIcuDischarge, templateIcuDischarge?.Mortality30DStatus, ref keyValuePairs, subjectId));
            IcuDischarge icuDischarge = new IcuDischarge
            {
                CauseofReadmission = CommonFunctions.GetData(sourceJson, null, templateIcuDischarge?.CauseofReadmission, ref keyValuePairs, subjectId),
                DateofReadmission = CommonFunctions.GetData(sourceJson, templateIcuDischarge?.CauseofReadmission, templateIcuDischarge?.DateofReadmission, ref keyValuePairs, subjectId),
                DischargeDisposition = CommonFunctions.GetData(sourceJson, templateIcuDischarge?.DateofReadmission, templateIcuDischarge?.DischargeDisposition, ref keyValuePairs, subjectId),
                DischargingUnit = CommonFunctions.GetData(sourceJson, templateIcuDischarge?.DischargeDisposition, templateIcuDischarge?.DischargingUnit, ref keyValuePairs, subjectId),
                IcuDischargeIcuDischarge = CommonFunctions.GetData(sourceJson, templateIcuDischarge?.DischargingUnit, templateIcuDischarge?.IcuDischargeIcuDischarge, ref keyValuePairs, subjectId),
                Mortality30DStatus = EnumProvider.TryParse<Mortality30DStatus>(EnumProvider.FormatStringForEnumCompare(morStatus), Mortality30DStatus.None),
                ReadmissionWithin30Days = CommonFunctions.GetData(sourceJson, templateIcuDischarge?.Mortality30DStatus, templateIcuDischarge?.ReadmissionWithin30Days, ref keyValuePairs, subjectId)
            };

            #endregion Icu Discharge

            return icuDischarge;
        }
```

Common function class is given below,

```
public static dynamic GetData(string sourceJson, dynamic oldTemplate, dynamic newTemplate, ref List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>> keyValuePairs,
           double subjectId, ArrayResult arrayResult = ArrayResult.Single)
        {
            if (keyValuePairs != null && oldTemplate != null && newTemplate != null && (oldTemplate.File == newTemplate?.File && oldTemplate.Sheet == newTemplate?.Sheet))
            
            {
                return GetSingleValuesFromList(keyValuePairs, newTemplate.Column, arrayResult);
            }
            else
            {
                //keyValuePairs = GetValuesFrom(sourceJson, newTemplate.File, newTemplate.Sheet, newTemplate.Column, subjectId);
                keyValuePairs = GetValuesFrom(sourceJson, newTemplate?.File, newTemplate?.Sheet, newTemplate?.Column, subjectId);
                return GetSingleValuesFromList(keyValuePairs, newTemplate?.Column, arrayResult);
            }
        }
```

Do i need to any change in the above functions? can i apply thread? how to achieve asynchronous functionality with the above code?

Comment: Wrap it into Task

Comment: I have already done it in the task

Comment: No, you don't ... marking method async doesn't make call on background thread. You need to start new Task

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to do this for every id?:

```
File.WriteAllText($"D:\out\awaitcheck{subjectId}.txt", stringBuilder.ToString());
```

Edit: This does not need to write a file per subjectId. Do this instead:

```
                foreach (var subjectId in subjectIds)
                {
                    var GetIcuDischargeTransform = icuDataTransform.GetIcuDischargeTransform(sourceJson, emrSchema, subjectId);
                    stringBuilder.Append($"var:GetIcuDischargeTransform({subjectId}): ").Append(" ").Append(DateTime.Now).AppendLine();
   
                    emrData.IcuDischarge = await GetIcuDischargeTransform;
                    stringBuilder.Append($"await:GetIcuDischargeTransform({subjectId}): ").Append(" ").Append(DateTime.Now).AppendLine();
                }
                File.WriteAllText($"D:\\out\\awaitcheck.txt", stringBuilder.ToString());
```

That will be writing a text file for every one, each bigger than the last. How many ids are there? Might be a lot of IO there.

The dynamic type is not fast:

```
List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>> ...
```

Maybe there is a specific type you can use? If not maybe 'object' is better? You are passing this keyValuePairs variable to each getdata method using 'ref' but it is already a reference type so that is not necessary (but is not likely slowing it down).

Finally, there are a lot of separate methods to get data. What is each of these doing? Is there a faster or simpler way to achieve it?

Edit:

I see you've added the GetData method but this does not show what the methods it calls do either. But I'm not sure this matters. I still don't think the dynamic type is necessary. I personally avoid it entirely in everything I code.

I expect the methods to get data from json are inefficient and could probably be replaced by having a properly defined model that represents the expected content of the json. Then you can simply deserialize it using the NewtonSoft JSON library.

Comment: This is for getting execution time for function. it have 8 functions are there(but in code, not specified). this just for knowing execution time of the function

Comment: our input is dynamic. that is why we use dynamic. List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>> ...

Comment: The write to text file should be outside of the loop, see edit.

Comment: Also, without knowing what the CommonFunctions.GetData method does, I can't say what's wrong.

Comment: CommonFunctions.GetData method added in the question.